# Temperature and the conductivity of sea water

Tags: electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics

I came across a table in Griffith *Introduction to Electrodynamics* (2nd edition, p 297), which shows a table of various resistivities for different materials. I found it surprising that sea water is listed as a semiconductor here.

[image: Griffith resistivity table]

As it turned out, I could not find much online agreeing or disagreeing with this. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor) introduces semiconductors as the following:

> A semiconductor is a material, which has an electrical conductivity value falling between that of a conductor, such as copper, and an insulator, such as glass. Its resistivity falls as its temperature rises; metals behave in the opposite way.

I am not sure about the second property here, and I was wondering if sea water, as an electrolyte solution, actually exhibits this effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked the Internet, and the Internet came through.  Yes, seawater conductivity does rise with temperature (graph from [*Temperature Effects on Conductivity of Seawater and Physiologic Saline,
Mechanism and Significance*, Sauerheber and Heinz, Chem Sci J 2015, 6:4](https://www.hilarispublisher.com/open-access/temperature-effects-on-conductivity-of-seawater-and-physiologic-salinemechanism-and-significance-2150-3494-1000109.pdf)).

So seawater meets the Wikipedia definition of a "semiconductor".

[image]

However, in the *same* reference, frozen seawater has a similar conductivity but a negative conductivity vs. temperature slope, presumably kicking it out of Wikipedia's definition of "semiconductor" and leaving it homeless.